# Not able to Display entered inputtext in same visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, inputtext

I have created Discount Integer variable in apex class and use it as a `inputText` in visualforce page and at the same time i need to display that entered `inputText`

here is my visualforce code :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockSection id="relatedInfo">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PW.PBEList}" var="PBE" rendered="{!PW.PBEList.size > 0}">
    <apex:column headerValue="Part Number">
        <apex:outputField value="{!PBE.Part_Number__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Description">
        <apex:outputField value="{!PBE.Description__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="List Price">
        <apex:outputField value="{!PBE.UnitPrice}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Discount">
        <apex:inputText value="{!Discount}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="saleprice" action="{!Calculation}" immediate="false"/>
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Sale Price" id="saleprice">
        <apex:inputText value="{!SalePrice}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
        <apex:inputText value="{!Quantity}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="exPrice" action="{!Calculation}"/>
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Extended Price" id="exPrice">
        <apex:inputText value="{!ExtendedPrice}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Cost">
        <apex:outputField value="{!PBE.Cost__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" id="Grouptotal">
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel style="display:block;width:590px;"/>
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group total Discount :  " />
    <apex:inputText value="{!Discount}"/>
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group total price :  " />
    <apex:inputText value="{!Total}"/>
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group total cost :  " />
    <apex:inputText value="{!SubTotal}"/>
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel />
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Group Margin :  " />
    <apex:inputText value="{!GroupTotal}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the good solution is to add a second action support on your inputText to update the second input text for each key pressed. Like this:

```
<apex:inputText id="firstInputDiscount" value="{!Discount}">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="saleprice" action="{!Calculation}" immediate="false"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onkeyup" rerender="secondInputDiscount" />
</apex:inputText>
```

And change the second input text like this:

```
<apex:inputText id="secondInputDiscount" value="{!Discount}">
     <apex:actionSupport event="onkeyup" rerender="firstInputDiscount" />
</apex:inputText>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53735/discussion-between-martin-lezer-and-wanttobeacoder).